Visual Studio does not show apple enterprise development team anymore
I was working on a c# maui app with Visual Studio 2022 for months and used provisioning profile from an enterprise account where i am member with development role.
After newest Visual Studio update to 17.10.0 the enterprise team does not show up anymore in visual studio. I can only see the team of my own individual apple developer account. Also Visual Studio for mac does not show the enterprise team anymore.
XCode still shows the enterprise team. Also on appstoreconnect and developer.apple.com i still can see the enterprise team.
I removed my apple account from the Visual Studio settings and added it again. Also tried with a new appstoreconnect key, but still cannot see the enterprise team in Visual Studio.
I installed the previous Version of Visual Studio (17.9.7) with the Visual Studio installer, but also with this version the enterprise team is not available for me.
Here's a screenshot of the settings in Visual Studio (where i am missing the enterprise team): 
And here's the screenshot of the corresponding settings at XCode: 
added info:
in the meantime i was able to build and distribute my project by manually putting the downloaded provisioning profile file to
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles

and the certificate to
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates


Do you mean that after adding the Enterprise Account in VS -> Tools -> Options -> Apple Accounts, it is not displayed in the Accounts list?

@user24884869 no; i don't have an enterprise account by myself. The individual account i am logging into is just a member of our companies enterprise account.

If you are only the member of your enterprise team, the enterprise development team will not be displayed in the Apple account list in VS, unless you use the Apple Developer account of the team holder.
In addition, if you need to use the provisioning profile of the enterprise account, you can download it directly through Xcode. For details, you can refer to Download your provisioning profile in Xcode.

I am just one developer of many. I do not hold admin rights to the enterprise team.

Even if you don't have admin privilege, if you need to use the provisioning profile, you can download it directly through Xcode. You can refer to the document I provided in my answer.

After adding your Apple developer account to Xcode, click the Manage Certificates... button. button to make sure your distribution certificates have been downloaded，然后click the Download Manual Profiles button to download your provisioning profiles. This allows you to bypass the vs download provisioning profile
